# Загрузка динамических библиотеки при старте программы

Tags: c++, qt

Динамические библиотеки подгружаются, на сколько я понимаю, только если потребовались функции из этой библиотеки. Можно ли загрузить все или хотя бы ту часть, которую я наверняка буду использовать, явно, во время старта программы?

Компилятор minGW.

Comment: Зависит от того как вы линкуетесь. Есть  load-time dynamic linking и есть run-time dynamic linking. Первый подгружает все библиотеки при старте .ехе, второй способ ручной (при вызове LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress) (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking). Чем вызван вопрос?

Comment: @goldstar_labs есть в библиотеки qt классQFileDialog, для сохранения файлов. Каждый раз когда я его использую происходит подгрузка библиотек. Что занимает время. Каждый раз когда я закрываю этот диалог происходит выгрузка.  Мне же нужно что бы эта библиотека была загружена при старте программы. И больше не выгружалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Динамические библиотеки подгружаются, на сколько я понимаю, только если потребовались функции из этой библиотеки.

На самом деле нет, поведение по умолчанию при [неявном связывании](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=vs-2017#implicit-linking) обратное: DLL загружается при запуске программы, если DLL недоступна или в ней отсутствует хотя бы одна нужная функция - программа аварийно завершается. DLL могут подгружаться позднее в случае явного связывания или использования [отложенной загрузки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2017) при неявном связывании.

> Можно ли загрузить все или хотя бы ту часть, которую я наверняка буду использовать, явно, во время старта программы

Если вы хотите явно загрузить какую-то библиотеку при старте программы, достаточно вызвать [LoadLibrary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw) в функции main до кода инициализации Qt и передать в нее имя DLL. Когда Qt повторно вызовет LoadLibrary с тем же именем DLL, это не приведет к повторной ее загрузке, а только увеличит счетчик ссылок на эту DLL. Аналогично, вызов FreeLibrary не выгрузит библиотеку, а лишь вернет счетчик ссылок в прежнее значение.

Comment: Всё правильно, но в  Qt библиотеки можно грузить с помощью мультиплатформенной `QLibrary::load`